# jQuery - bpopup plugin, I need help in reproducing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bpopup

I have tried everything I can think of - including including every bpopup and jquery javascript file, even a .json file I found on one example, but can not seem to get this thing to work.  I have all of the script files included in the same folder as the example I am trying to run:

**bpopup** (`jQuery plugin`), [Code Example](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/#Usage).  My Non-working [example here](http://www.thinkinginnovative.com/popupexample/bpopup/Brianspopupexample.html).

It is this last link that I am trying to get to work, as just a starting point.  I have looked through the [examples here](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/). It shows just some of the cool things I would like to use.  downloading the page and accompanying files and opening it in Dreamweaver doesn't work for me either..

Any help would be astronomically appreciated.  the jfiddle examples work, I however can not see which script files they are linking to - they must be uploaded in to jfiddle somehow.  I have searched other issues when trying to use bpopup on stackoverflow, I however can not find a full, non-broken (in to various pieces) solution i.e. the whole html page along with the script files linked to embedded in the head tag.

Thanks much,

Brian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add `jQuery.js`, `jquery.bpopup-0.9.4.min.js`, `jquery.easing.1.3.js` and a style sheet. For example,

**JS:**

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.bpopup-0.9.4.min.js
http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js
```

**StyleSheet from their site:**

```
http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/style.min.css
```

And this code

```
$(function(){
    $('#pop').click(function(){
        $('#popup').bPopup();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
    <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
    If you can't get it up use<br />
    <span class="logo">bPopup</span>
</div>
```

[**Works Fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVQ3N/) (Click Popup button).

**CSS:** (Used in popup) with [**another example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVQ3N/2/)

```
#popup, .bMulti {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #999;
    color: #111;
    display: none;
    min-width: 450px;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
}

#popup .logo {
    color: #2B91AF;
    font: bold 325% 'Petrona',sans;
}

.button.b-close, .button.bClose {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: none;
    font: bold 131% sans-serif;
    padding: 0 6px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -7px;
    top: -7px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #2B91AF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Update :** In your example (given link), you have loaded `jQuery` three times and most importantly, you've loaded the `plugin (bPopup)` more than once and at last `jQuery` again, so `jQuery` object changed. So, just load a single verion of `jQuery` first and then load `jquery.easing.js` and then load `bPopup.js` (min/expanded). Also load `stylesheet` (style.js) with styles declared for your `popup` div.

Comment: Thank you, Not sure why I was having so much trouble with this.  I really appreciate you breaking it down; it really sucks when the simplest things drive you crazy and you just can not figure out where the error is.  Again, very appreciated!

Comment: How i can load external Page inside the Popup, i used -- loadUrl -- but not working at all, any help please.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the same code of yours and it's working fine. Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/fR9EQ/). The problem seems to be with the multiple jQuery versions you are calling. In total you need the following two files to get this working:

- `jquery.js`
- `jquery.bpopup.min.js` or `jquery.bpopup.js`

If you wish to learn more about what happens when you try to use multiple versions of jQuery and how you can actually do it, you should refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Other than that, you should always load jQuery prior to using any jQuery based plugin.